# JSF 2.0 NullPointerException exception after submitting commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

After migrating JSF from 1.2 to 2.0 I begin to receive exception after submitting commandButton:

> javax.faces.FacesException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:222)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.getRenderedViewId(FaceletViewHandler.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:553)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:207)
>
> ... 26 more

JSF markup:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="layout.jsp">
    <ui:define name="title">Редактирование шаблона</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">                
            <p>
                <a href="/templates.jsf">Все шаблоны</a>
            </p>
            <h:form>
                <h:inputHidden value="#{template.id}" />
                Name: <h:inputText value="#{template.name}"/> <br/>
                Content Type: <h:inputText value="#{template.contentType}"/> <br/>
                Content: <h:inputTextarea value="#{template.content}"/> <br/>
                Description: <h:inputTextarea value="#{template.description}"/> <br/>
                <h:commandButton value="Сохранить" action="#{template.submit}"> 
                </h:commandButton>

            </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your other question you mentioned that you're using Mojarra 2.0, but the stacktrace indicates that you still have MyFaces 1.1 in the classpath. Get rid of it. You cannot mix multiple JSF implementations.

Comment: I thought than I can change my dependency to myfaces 2.0. I'm now using Mojarra 2.0 and it works! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer on your questions to accepted by ticking the checkmark. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: I'd love to, but I still have no reputation. And as I understand, I can not vote or pick up the answers.