# f:verbatim tag stops working when inside a dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I posted this to the PrimeFaces user forum but I think they are too busy to look into it, so I thought I would try here.

I have server-side string that has markup in it, so when I want it rendered I do this:

```
            <p:panel>                    
                <f:verbatim>
                    #{daBean.markedUpString}
                </f:verbatim>
            </p:panel>
```

This works fine, but not if the same tag is used inside a **p:dataTable** -- either with or without the **p:panel** enclosure.   What gets rendered is a **div class="ui-dt-c"** element with nothing in it.  To test, if I take out the **f:verbatim** tag the marked-up text gets escaped and rendered.

I don't know if this should be considered a bug or not, but does anyone know of a work-around for this?  This is with PrimeFaces 3.0.M3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<f:verbatim>` tag is intented to hold **plain** text/HTML, not JSF components nor EL expressions. The tag is a leftover from JSF 1.0/1.1 ages when it was not possible to inline plain text/HTML between JSF components. The tag is deprecated in JSF2. You do not need it anymore.

Your concrete functional requirement is thus displaying some HTML string from a managed bean unescaped. For that you should use `<h:outputText>` with `escape="false"`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{daBean.markedUpString}" escape="false" />
```

#### See also:

- [Getters inside f:verbatim called before form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502465/getters-inside-fverbatim-called-before-form-submission)
- [JSF/Facelets: why is it not a good idea to mix JSF/Facelets with HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474178/jsf-facelets-why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-mix-jsf-facelets-with-html-tags)
- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0)