# When and why we use the verbatim in jsf?

Tags: jsf, verbatim

As i am now working on jsf i want to know why we use the tag verbatim in jsf and what is the significance of it ?

Any help would be of great appreciation.

Answer (score 6):

Since you've tagged your question with [jsf-2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2) the answer is: **you shouldn't use it**.

It is deprecated in JSF 2.0. It was a part of JSF 1.X and used to hold plain HTML. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7540743/1411160), [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/verbatim.html) (since 2.1 there is an additional info: *The use of this element has been deprecated in Facelets for JSF 2.0 and beyond*) and [the usage example](https://web.archive.org/web/20171203143458/http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_verbatim.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information , i didn't know that it is not a part of JSF2.0

Comment: But may i know the use of it in the JSF 1.X

Comment: Sanket, note the blue words in the answer. Those are links. Put your mouse over it and click them.