# When does a JSF 2.0 ViewScoped Bean die?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I would like to have a Ajax-Based Tabbed interface in my website.

I would also like to have a bean for each of the tabs.
These beans are expected to be "*born*" when entering the tab and "*die*" when leaving the tab.

**Important** - The switch between tabs must be an AJAX event and not a full page redraw.

I thought `@ViewScoped` is the appropriate scope for this type of behaviour but I am stuck on the issue of killing the bean when leaving a tab. To my best knowledge, a `@ViewScoped` bean will only die on a redirect/navigation event.

Is there a proper way to make the `@ViewScoped` bean die? Should I use a different scope?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Reading BalusC's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831888/does-view-scope-bean-survive-navigation-jsf) question is good indication:

> A view scoped bean lives as long as you interact with the same view
>   (i.e. you return void or null in bean action method). When you
>   navigate away to another view, e.g. by clicking a link or by returning
>   a different action outcome, then the view scoped bean will be trashed
>   by end of render response and not be available in the next request.

So, according to this, I could return a different outcome from an action method and make the `@ViewScoped` bean die.
But to do this I have to disable navigation after an outcome from an action method (JSF 2 implicit navigation) and I don't know how to do that (or if that's the right way to achieve my goal)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265433/how-and-when-is-a-view-scope-bean-destroyed-in-jsf/15391453#15391453) to the question *"How and when is a view scope bean destroyed in JSF?"* might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use just one ViewScoped bean having the data to show as a simple POJO property. The pages will be lazy intialized.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean {

    private WizardData wizardData;

    public WizardData getWizardData() {
        if (wizardData == null) {
            wizardData = new WizardData();
        }
        return wizardData;
    }

    public void setWizardData(WizardData wizardData) {
        this.wizardData = wizardData;
    }
}

public class WizardData {
    private WizardPage1 page1;
    private WizardPage2 page2;

    public WizardPage1 getPage1() {
        if (page1 == null) {
            page1 = new WizardPage1();
        }
        return page1;
    }

    public void setPage1(WizardPage1 page1) {
        this.page1 = page1;
    }

    public WizardPage2 getPage2() {
        if (page2 == null) {
            page2 = new WizardPage2();
        }
        return page2;
    }

    public void setPage2(WizardPage2 page2) {
        this.page2 = page2;
    }
}
```

So on pages the pojos will be created when you use them, e.g.

```
<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.wizardData.page1.someTextToShow}"/>
```