# Strange behaviour of page with @ViewScoped when is opened twice

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I have bean which looks like below:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "reportDetailsBean")  
@ViewScoped  
public class ReportDetailsBean implements Serializable {  
    // content...  
}
```

and JSF page with this part of code:

```
...  
<a4j:queue id="reportQueue" status="globalStatus" />  
<a4j:form id="reportForm#{reportDetailsBean.report.id}" ajaxSingle="true" ajaxSubmit="true" eventsQueue="reportQueue" reRender="reportForm" styleClass="">  
    ...  
    <a4j:outputPanel id="salesItemNameHeader" layout="block" style="cursor: pointer;" rendered="#{reportDetailsBean.model.rowCount gt 0}">  
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.reportDetails_salesItem}" />  
        <rich:spacer width="4px" />  
        <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="reportTable" action="#{reportDetailsBean.model['sortTableByColumn']}" status="globalStatus" ajaxSingle="true">  
            <a4j:actionparam name="columnIndex" value="bySalesItemName" assignTo="#{reportDetailsBean.model['currentSortModelItem']}" />  
        </a4j:support>  
    </a4j:outputPanel>  
...
```

JSF page handles param id from URL. Correct adress of this JSF page is for example `localhost/reportDetails.jsp?reportId=37`.

Problem occurs when I want open reportDetails.jsp two times - witn different parameters.

There are two scenarios. First one:
1) Open `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=1`
2) Open `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=2`
3) reference to `ReportDetailsBean` instance from `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=1` was changed by reference to `ReportDetailsBean` instance from `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=2`

Second one:
1) Open `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=1`
2) Click few times on links like is shown above
3) Open `reportDetails.jsp?reportId=2`
4) Everything is ok - each view has own instance of `ReportDetailsBean`

Could someone explain me why in the first scenario reference to isntance of backbean is changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ViewScoped` bean they will live for one view. If you enter another address in browser or to redirection to another page there is another view, and another instance of your view scoped bean.

**See also:**

- [Does view scope bean survive Navigation JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831963/759126)

Comment: I agree with that but why in first scenario instance from the first view is changed?

Comment: How you are navigating? Entering address in browser or forwarding or redirecting?

Comment: From the link on another page.