# Java EE 6 without JSF: what are the most web developer friendly alternatives?

Tags: jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, java-ee-6, template-engine

Having worked over the last years with a quite "classical" technology stack: Java SE + Spring Web MVC + Freemarker template engine (as well as doing some development with Play! Framework) and a lot of client-side logic built in JavaScript resp. jQuery, I am now wondering what are the best options for a straight rendering layer when embracing now Java EE 6? My team (consisting of web developers with a lot of HTML/CSS/JavaScript know-how) wants to avoid JSF by all means. Which frameworks can you recommend? One option might be probably [mustache.java](http://mustache.java), it would be fantastic if you could share your expierences ...

Related questions, which do cover the pros and cons about JSF (2.0), but unfortunately not what lightweight alternatives are available:

- [Java-EE: Cleaner and simpler alternatives to JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307205/java-ee-cleaner-and-simpler-alternatives-to-jsf)
- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) by Google or [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). Haven't worked on either of them but I am aware of those. Also, once you move out of the Java EE 6 spec it is kind of more involved on integrated these frameworks into Java EE programming paradigm.

Comment: And what would you use for delivering those base HTML pages? ... or go for a pure JAX-RS driven approach?

Comment: @ngeek Yes. REST is what I am thinking. I've asked a question earlier regarding the same in SO. Look under "angularjs" tag.