# Getting error while running a simple JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I am getting following exception while  I am trying to run a basic JSF application . I am using JSF1.1 , JDK 6 and tomcat 6.0.18 for the same.

exception

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error testing property 'lastname' in bean of type null
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:209)


root cause 

javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error testing property 'lastname' in bean of type null
    com.sun.faces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getType(PropertyResolverImpl.java:342)
    com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.getType(ArraySuffix.java:240)
    com.sun.faces.el.impl.ComplexValue.getType(ComplexValue.java:208)
    com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getType(ValueBindingImpl.java:345)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:111)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:713)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:638)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:849)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:412)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:170)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:912)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:342)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:78)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:200)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:90)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
```

Following are the files I have created for the same :

//jsfmbean.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>

<f:view>
<html>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<h:form id="form1" >
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{text2}" />
<h:inputText id="text2" value="#{player.lastname}" />
 <h:commandButton action="success" value="success" />
 <h:commandButton action="#{player.changeName}" value="failure" />
 </h:form>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

//faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">



<faces-config>

  <application>

  <locale-config>

  <default-locale>en</default-locale>  

  </locale-config>

  </application>

  <navigation-rule> 


  <from-view-id> 
   /jsfevent.jsp 
  </from-view-id> 

  <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>success</from-outcome> 
  <to-view-id>/mathew.jsp</to-view-id> 
   </navigation-case> 

   <navigation-case> 
   <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome> 
   <to-view-id>/amy.jsp</to-view-id> 
   </navigation-case> 
  </navigation-rule> 



  <navigation-rule> 
<from-view-id>/jsfmbean.jsp</from-view-id> 
<navigation-case> 
<from-outcome>success</from-outcome> 
<to-view-id>/mathew.jsp</to-view-id> 
</navigation-case> 
</navigation-rule> 

<managed-bean> 
<managed-bean-name>player</managed-bean-name> 
<managed-bean-class> 
ourdemo.player 
</managed-bean-class> 

<managed-bean-scope> 
session 
</managed-bean-scope> 

<managed-property> 
<property-name>firstname</property-name> 
<property-type>java.lang.String</property-type>
<value>Mahatma</value> 
</managed-property> 

<managed-property> 
<property-name>lastname</property-name> 
<property-type>java.lang.String</property-type>
<value>Gandhiji</value> 
</managed-property> 

</managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

//Player.java

```
package ourdemo; 
import javax.faces.context.*; 
import javax.faces.component.*; 
import javax.faces.validator.*; 
public class Player 
{ 
String firstname ;  
String lastname ; 


public void setFirstname(String a) 
{ 
firstname=a; 
} 
public String getFirstname() 
{ 
return firstname; 
} 
//---------- 
public void setLastname(String b) 
{ 
lastname=b; 
} 
public String  getLastname() 
{ 
return lastname; 
} 
//-------------------
public void changeName() 
{ 
lastname= firstname+" "+lastname; 
}
```

}

Please help ...

Comment: >I am using JSF1.1 - please do yourself and everyone else who has to read or work with your code a favor and use at least JSF 1.2, but better JSF 2.0 (works with Tomcat 6). If at any length possible, use JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean pointed to by `#{player}` has not been initialized properly, so the `#{player.lastname}` throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive. You've created a managed bean with full qualified class name of `ourdemo.Player`, but yet you're declaring the bean in `faces-config.xml` as `ourdemo.player` (note the lowercase `p` instead of the uppercase `P`). This way JSF can't find and create the bean class, which results that `#{player}` is `null` which in turn results in this exception.

Fix it accordingly:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>player</managed-bean-name> 
    <managed-bean-class>ourdemo.Player</managed-bean-class> 
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: I fully agree with Arjan Tijms in the question comment: use JSF 2.0 or newer if ever possible. JSF 1.1 is obsolete for over 5 years and has so many disadvantages. If you're using JSF 1.1 due to business restrictions, [convince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) your manager. Or if you're using JSF 1.1 because you're reading outdated books/tutorials, throw them away and read the proper ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your faces-config.xml is wrong.

class name declaration must be the same as

```
<managed-bean-class> 
ourdemo.Player 
</managed-bean-class>
```