# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, primefaces

I have a JSF 2.0 project with PrimeFaces 3.0.0.M3 on Glassfish.

When I run it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using JSP instead of Facelets? Please provide the view code.

Comment: And guys I have a other problem.

when I use @ManagedBean ,I dont reach the bean from the page,
what may it caused by?What is the Differences between JSP and Facelsets

Comment: One problem at a time please. For a new problem, just ask new question. As to the current problem, please edit your question to include the view code causing this problem. Please also confirm if you're really using JSP instead of Facelets (the stacktrace namely hints that and PrimeFaces doesn't support JSP views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following line,

```
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:214)
```

I assume that you're *actually* using the legacy JSP instead of its successor Facelets as view technology (if you were using Facelets, you would have seen `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy` here).

JSF 2.x at its own works fine on JSP, but the PrimeFaces component library does not support JSP anymore since PrimeFaces 2.2 for various reasons (it boils down to "not worth the maintenance effort"). If you want to use PrimeFaces 3.0, you need to upgrade to Facelets. Facelets is a XML based view technology which offers enormous a lot of advantages over JSP. It's already bundled as default view technology in JSF 2.x, you do not need to install or configure anything separately.

#### See also:

- [Our Facelets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info)
- [Disadvantages of JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) (a bit of history)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Introduction to Facelets](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)
- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassfish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html)