# JSF 2.0 error displaying h:messages

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to figure out a way to get h:messages to display with the JQuery UI highlight box around it.  But by putting it the f:verbatim tag it isn't rendering.  If I try anything like splitting it out into 2 f:verbatim tags around the HTML I will get:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 25] The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "

".

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{uploadBean.hasMessage}">
    <div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0 .7em;"> 
            <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            **<h:messages />**
    </p>
    </div>
 </div>
</f:verbatim>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `<f:verbatim>` to render partials containing JSF components. There it is not for. The `<f:verbatim>` is a leftover of old and dark JSF 1.0/1.1 ages when it was not possible to inline plain HTML tags in a JSF page. Even more, the `<f:verbatim>` is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0.

Use `<h:panelGroup>` instead.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{uploadBean.hasMessage}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

When looking for JSF 2.x resources/answers, make sure that you're reading JSF 2.x targeted ones, not JSF 1.x targeted ones. The change is too big and a lot of things are done differently/better in JSF 2.x than in JSF 1.x.

#### See also:

- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) (a bit of history)