# JSF 1.1: Conditionally hide raw HTML and tags

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to change an JSF 1.1 page to conditionally hide parts of the page. The page is built using intermixed raw HTML and tags. Specifically I have the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td><h:inputText ... /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td><h:inputText ... /></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more stuff, including <h:dataTable>
</table>
```

I would like to wrap this in a tag that conditionally hides this entire table, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Here's what I've tried:

- Wrap the markup in a `<h:panelGroup rendered="...">`. While this correct shows/hides the markup, all raw the HTML is stripped from the generated HTML.
- Wrap the markup in a `<f:verbatim>`. This does not work as the verbatim tag does not have a rendered attribute in JSF 1.1
- Wrap the whole thing in a `<h:panelGroup rendered="..."><f:verbatim>` combo. This has the same effect as the first attempt.
- I've also tried `<f:view>` and `<f:subview>` to no avail.

I know that it is possible to include JSTL tags in a JSF page and use `<c:if>` but I would like to avoid this situation. Any ideas?

NOTE: I realize that it is (by some at least) considered bad practice to mix HTML and JSF, however this page was created by someone else, I just have to modify it (its a somewhat large page and the HTML above is just a small snippet from it)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either replace `<table>` by `<h:panelGrid>`.

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputText value="Foo" />
  <h:inputText ... />

  <h:outputText value="Bar" />
  <h:inputText ... />

  <!-- more stuff, including <h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Or make use of CSS display:none/block:

```html
<table style="display: ${some condition ? 'none' : 'block'};">
```

Or just upgrade to JSF 1.2. Technically, a JSF 1.1 web application can easily be upgraded to JSF 1.2 without any code changes. It's only a matter of updating the JARs and changing the `faces-config.xml` root declaration to replace the JSF 1.1 DTD by a JSF 1.2 XSD. JSF 1.2 comes with an improved view handler which kills the `<f:verbatim>` nightmare (i.e. it is not needed anymore). It also comes with many, many bugfixes and performance enhancements you'd be very thankful for.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as to your statement that mixing HTML and JSF is a bad practice, this isn't necessarily true. At least not since JSF 1.2 anymore. On JSF 1.0/1.1 you'd need to use `<f:verbatim>` which is in turn indeed a pain to develop/maintain. This caused the wrong myth that mixing JSF/HTML is "bad". See also [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) for a bit of history on that.