# How to make JSF EL function inside a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Does Anyone know how to make this properly work?
I have to put some JSF EL inside the `script` tag, but the renderer isn't recognizing it.

```
    <f:verbatim>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#paginator").paginate({
                count: #{parceirosFrontControl.paginator.pagesTotal}, // total of pages
                start: #{parceirosFrontControl.currPage}, // current page
                display: #{parceirosFrontControl.paginator.pagesVisible}, // amount of visible pages
                border: false,
                text_color: '#888',
                background_color: '#EEE',   
                text_hover_color: 'black',
                background_hover_color: '#CFCFCF'
            });
        });
    </script>
    </f:verbatim>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I personally prefer to place hiddenInputs which holds the this kind of values and access them with jquery selector like `$("idOFHiddenInputID").val()` , b.t.w are you using primefaces datatable with pagination ?

Comment: Daniel, that's a good idea, I will try. I usually use primefaces and the built in p:dataTable with pagination. But in this case it is a pre defined layout that I'm filling, which for I'm using ui:repeat tag.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it worked very well!

Comment: Hidden inputs are plain clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `<f:verbatim>` tag. It is blocking the EL expressions from being evaluated.

This old JSF 1.x artifact serves an entirely different purpose and has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/verbatim.html) since JSF 2.0. Do not ever use it.

#### See also:

- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0/3646940#3646940) - a bit of history about f:verbatim

Comment: Thanks, its indeed work well if I remove the <f:verbatim> tag, despite my netbeans that doesn't understand this syntax at all. Do you use this same IDE?

Comment: You're welcome. No, I use Eclipse. Apparently your Netbeans setup still thinks it's a JSF 1.x project or so.

Comment: @BalusC you prefer placing js code inside your xhtml files just to avoid the hidden inputs? Also if you wish to update some value in your bean with ajax , how would you then access the updated value from js code embedded into your xhtml ? I mean , you can't refer the js code with `render` of `f:ajax`

Comment: @Daniel: Hidden inputs are clumsy if the sole purpose is to assign JS variables, as in OP's case.

Comment: @BalusC , ok , but usually one wold like to run his js code several times , each time with updated value (a value that should be synced with the bean value...)