# Difference between jsf 1.2 and jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have worked in jsf 1.2, rich faces and using hibernate ORM. I want to ask, how my project will change if i convert it to jsf 2.0 and prime faces. what can be the reason to shift to jsf 2.0? primitive question but i want to know from the experts the primary reason why would one shift from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: Among others , you will be able to use ajax out of the box... (much better user experience...) + View Scope + Its more stable etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0)

Comment: and on a related note: [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)

Comment: thanks BalusC that answers my question.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, in a JSF 2.0 you will get more functionallity then JSF 1.2
Like take a look at simple datatable tag in JSF 1.2 it is much more complex for like simple crud ops where in a JSF 2.0 all your code will be well optimised. 
Plus like when you want to add some extra features and functionallity to your existing project, you will easily get support of external libraries.
Likewise when you are getting a error in JSF 1.2 it is more difficult to solve and get guide because very less resources available on it.
And on a last like it is very old version of JSF so I would suggest to move on JSF 2.0

Comment: Hi, Bad suggestion... Move should be to JSF 2.3 (JSF 2.0 is 9 years old) And when switching, make sure modern tutorials are used (using CDI and not JSF managed beans)

Comment: Yeah I know that moving on a JSF 2.0 isn't very good idea but like it is better than using JSF 1.2 and in a some workplaces there are also restriction of using some specific version of perticular framework. That's why I suggested to move on JSF 2.0

Comment: If a company still has a requirement to use a 9 year old version when migrating from a 12 year old version, it should instanty go bankrupt ;-)

Comment: You don't understand that what I am saying.. Like in a my company we have a ready product on JSF 1.2 which is made 10 years ago .. So here we are still works on JSF 1.2 for customisation for clients and like for moving on JSF 2.3 we need to change all the data and it is more difficult .

Comment: Same problem with moving to 2.0... Just **never ever** upgrade from 1.2 to 2.0, but to 2.3 that is what **_I_** am stating, which **you** don't understand.