# jQuery UI Datepicker works on <input> but not on <h:inputText>

Tags: jquery, html, jsf-2

I'm trying to use [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). In same JSF page, it works on HTML `<input>` tag, but not on JSF `<h:inputText>` tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h:inputText id="mask-date" class="form-control mask" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control mask" id="mask-date"/>
    <span class="help-block blue">mm/dd/yyyy</span>
</div>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Code snippets are for providing runnable demo's using HTML/CSS/JS. it'll not interpret your jsf tags. I converted them to normal code blocks. That being said, please don't dump the source of entire libraries and plugins in question. Instead provide a link to their documentation, or tag it in question if a tag is available..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<h:inputText ... class="form-control mask" />
```

The `class` attribute isn't supported on [`<h:inputText>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputText.html). Instead, it's named `styleClass`.

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="form-control mask" />
```

This is true for all other JSF components. You should also have noticed the absence of the `class` attribute in the JSF-generated HTML `<input>` element when taking the effort to do rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser.

The attribute name is different from the HTML counterpart, because `class` is a reserved keyword in Java and therefore it isn't possible to have a `private String class;` field in the UI component class.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time.Actually I am new to JSF and I don't know the future scope of JSF , I have heard that it is an old framework. Is it true?

Comment: JSF is indeed an old framework. It exist almost a decade. But you're actually not working with decade-old codebase ;) Mojarra has a new release at least once a month. The JSF spec also keeps evolving and improving. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0. And as a starter looking for valuable resources you may find https://jsf.zeef.com helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases JSF tags not pure HTML tags but constructed from  multiple HTML tags, for example

```
<div id="input> 
<input ... />
</div>
```

And id of JSF tag not pointing to `<input>` tag but to outer `<div>`. You should view your outcome page code in HTML and correct your selector accordingly.