# SelectManyCheckbox does not find its child components

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I need your help is solving the error in the log. In my jsp, I am having selectmanycheckbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="true" %> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:form>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{com.favoriteCar2}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{com.favoriteCar2Value}" />

        </h:selectManyCheckbox>

        <br/>


        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{com.favoriteCar3}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{com.favoriteCar3Value}" />
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="results" />
        <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" />

    </h:form>
```

and mybean:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class com implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7134492943336358840L;

        public String[] favoriteCar1;
                public String[] favoriteCar2;
                public String[] favoriteCar3;
                public String[] favoriteCar4;

                public String[] getFavoriteCar2Value()
                {
                        favoriteCar2 = new String [5];
                        favoriteCar2[0] = "116";
                        favoriteCar2[1] = "118";
                        favoriteCar2[2] = "X1";
                        favoriteCar2[3] = "Series 1 Coupe";
                        favoriteCar2[4] = "120";

                        return favoriteCar2;
                }

                public String getFavoriteCar2InString()
                {
                        return Arrays.toString(favoriteCar2);
                }


                private static Map<String, Object> car3Value;
                static
                {
                        car3Value = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                        car3Value.put("Car3 - 316", "BMW 316");
                        car3Value.put("Car3 - 318", "BMW 318");
                        car3Value.put("Car3 - 320", "BMW 320");
                        car3Value.put("Car3 - 325", "BMW 325");
                        car3Value.put("Car3 - 330", "BMW 330");
                }

                public Map<String, Object> getFavoriteCar3Value()
                {
                        return car3Value;
                }
                public String getFavoriteCar3InString() {
                        return Arrays.toString(favoriteCar3);
                }

}
```

The log is showing the error and no checkbox is shown in the jsp:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for component type javax.faces.SelectMany(j_id_id2).  Found [Ljava.lang.String

Even I tried static children and it is not populating them.

So can you please help

Comment: Have you managed reproducing the error using static children? It seems the Java code is unecessary for the concrete error. Also, please append your JSP namespaces.

Comment: your managed bean name is" user" and in your jsp you are using "com", is that a mistake in the question only ?

Comment: @Smutje Even static it is not coming

Comment: @Tarik yes in the question and I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `SelectItems` value is a `String[]`, see the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/selectItems.html) regarding the `value` attribute of SelectItems in JSF 1.2 :

> Value binding expression pointing at a List or array of SelectItem
>   instances containing the information for these options.

You are also returning the value of your `selectManyCheckbox` in the SelectItems which doesn't make sense, you should better learn more about how to use `SelectItems`. You can find many examples in the [selectOneMenu wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) which is very similar to the `selectManyCheckbox`, Or in [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnask/index.html) (Note that this links are JSF 2.0 but that may help you to understand the concept).

Regarding your example, that should be something like this:

```
private List<SelectItem> favoriteCar2Value; 


//  (we will add only a getter, setter is not necessary)
public List<SelectItem> getFavoriteCar2Value() {

     favoriteCar2Value = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

     favoriteCar2Value.add(new SelectItem("116", "116 label"));
     favoriteCar2Value.add(new SelectItem("118", "118 label"));
     favoriteCar2Value.add(new SelectItem("X1", "X1 label"));
     favoriteCar2Value.add(new SelectItem("Series 1 Coupe", "Series 1 Coupe label"));
     favoriteCar2Value.add(new SelectItem("120", "120 label"));

     return favoriteCar2Value;

}
```

Finnaly, maybe it's time for you to consider migrating to JSF 2.0 which may let you working with facelets instead of JSP, benefit from Ajax support... For a clear comparative see: [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0/3646940#3646940)

Comment: Note that the OP seems to already have JSF2 in at least the compiletime classpath (those bean annotations would otherwise not have compiled).

Comment: @BalusC Yes I didn't paid attention to the annotations! I just saw the Tag and using JSP!

Comment: @maasmaas are you using JSF 2.0 with JSP files ?

Comment: @Tarik, earlier I was using and then now my files are ending with .jsf