# Query regarding JSF AJAX?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have implemented ajax in an jsf app using jquery, the ajax request bypass the '/faces' and directly call the deployed restful services. I am thinking of using Richfaces for jsf ajax, can you guys tell me few things that richfaces jsf CAN do that jQuery ajax can't.

Thanks!
Tarun

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces is one of many JSF component libraries out there.  The benefits of using any JSF component library (Richfaces, Icefaces, Primefaces, etc...) is that you get a feature rich control set with a good deal of AJAX functionality built into many of its controls.

I personally use and prefer Primefaces as it seems to have the most feature rich controls however it can be buggy.  Richfaces isn't as nice in my opinion but it seems more stable.

Check out the demos to see for yourself what they have to offer because they come with a lot of functionality out of box.

http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/demos

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf

Comment: what about the difference b/w jquery ajax and richfaces ajax?