# Can't access javascript file in jsf component

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a jsf component that must access to a javascript file, i added this whith outputScript as in the code bellow, I get an error in the generated html,  and the javascript can't be reached.
The javascript file is located in document_root/js directory

How can i resolve this problem, thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head><title>(For validation only)</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<composite:interface/>
<composite:implementation>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="messages.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="DateValidation.js" />

<h:form id="f">
    <h:outputText value="Date" />
    <h:inputText id="dateA" 
        onblur="return validateDateField('f:dateA');">
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>   

</composite:implementation>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the generated html i get this line: <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>

Comment: i dont know jsf try `name="./js/messages.js"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files have to be placed in the `/resources` subfolder. So, you should have the following in the public webcontent:

- `/resources/js/DateValidation.js`
- `/resources/js/messages.js`

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your composite component approach is pretty awkward. I'd suggest to check out [composite-component](/questions/tagged/composite-component) tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I can now reach the javascript file but I get a javascript error because the id of my inputText is prepend whith j_idt6 so the id of my inputText became j_idt6:f:dateA instead of f:dateA. have you please an idea to get around this issue.

Comment: That's a different problem for which you should in essence have asked a new question. It has however already been asked several times before, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132061/how-to-refer-to-a-jsf-component-id-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery