# JSF2.0 - InputTextArea inside Dialog cannot be retrieved via Jquery during the dialog's onShow event

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have the following dialog inside my .xhtml page.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="exampleDialog" onShow="fillTextArea()" >
    <p:tabView id="tabView">
        <p:tab id="exampleTab" title="Example">
            <p:inputTextarea id="someInputTextArea" autoResize="false"
                value="" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</p:dialog>
```

The dialog is shown when a button is clicked. The `fillTextArea` javascript function is defined inside script tags at the head of the document.

```
function fillTextArea() {
    console.log(jQuery("textarea[id='someInputTextArea']")); // logs empty array []
    console.log($("[id='someInputTextArea']")); // logs empty array []
    jQuery("textarea[id='someInputTextArea']").val('xxx'); // does nothing
}
```

What's the problem? Why can't I retrieve the input text area?

Instead of using the `onShow` event of the `Dialog`, I tried:

```
exampleDialog.show();
fillTextArea();
```

just in case. But this didn't work neither. I'm trying to set the contents of the `inputTextArea`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the id attribute for your textarea set to when you view HTML source in your web browser?

Comment: It's `tabView:headCodeTextArea_input`. But that doesn't mean I have to access it with such ugly syntax, does it?

Comment: Well it works when I access with that id. But isn't there another way to get around this? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery works on the JSF-generated HTML DOM tree, not on the JSF source code. JSF components do not necessarily generate the same client ID (the HTML element ID) as you have specified in the component ID. They may be prepended with IDs of the parent [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) components. The `<h:form>` and `<p:tabView>` are such components.

Open the page in webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* and locate the generated HTML code of the `<p:inputTextarea>`. It'll look something like this:

```html
<textarea id="formId:tabViewId:textareaId">
```

You need to specify **exactly** this ID in the jQuery selector.

```
$("[id='formId:tabViewId:textareaId']");
```

#### See also:

- [How to refer to a JSF component Id in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132061/how-to-refer-to-a-jsf-component-id-in-jquery)
- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, this works. A quick question, can I instead refer to it as `xxx.val()` assuming I have `widgetVar="xxx"`?

Comment: PF Widget objects are not directly jQuery objects. They have however a `.jq` property which returns the wrapped jQuery object. So `xxx.jq.val()` should do. An alternative is to recreate the jQuery object based on the ID as obtained by `xxx.jqId`: `$(xxx.jqId).val()`. This way the element will be recreated in jQuery context instead of PF Widget context. I've experienced that `xxx.jq.foo()` fails for some jQuery functions because information about parents/childs is not up to date.