# Jquery in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jquery, jsf

im newbie in Jquery , i want to do a placeholder in jsf , something like this : http://niklaskoehler.de/demos/vordefinierter-text/ . I've the next code :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $ = jQuery;
    var Element = "#email";
    var InputText = "Placeholder demo";

    $(Element).val(InputText);

    alert("sup bro"); //this alert works

    $(Element).bind('focus',function(){
        $(this).addClass('focus');
        if($(this).val()==InputText){

            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).bind('blur',function(){
        if($(this).val()==""){
            $(this).val(InputText);
            $(this).removeClass('focus');
        }
    });
});


</script> 

</head>
```

And this is my form :

```
<h:form>
       <div class="form-item">
            <h:inputText id="email" title="Email" value="#{UserAction.email}"/>
       </div>
</h:form>
```

And nothing happen with the input , what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't work with JSF component tree in server side. Instead, it works with HTML DOM tree in client side. In case of JSF, you should instead be looking at JSF-generated HTML output while writing jQuery. As you're encountering rather unpredictable HTML element IDs like `pbGfb9435b3_2d720d_2d478d_2d8183_2d657b3839216b_j_id1:j_idt5:email`, you're likely running a JSF portlet instead of servlet. The `pgXxx` ID prefix occurs on portlets only.

As a word of advice, don't select non-unique elements by ID. Select by class name instead.

E.g.

```html
<h:inputText ... styleClass="email" />
```

with

```
var selector = ".email";
var inputText = "Placeholder demo";
$(selector).val(inputText);
```

*(I took the liberty to fix poor variable names; they should not start with uppercase and the CSS selector is not an element)*

#### See also:

- [How to refer to a JSF component Id in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132061/how-to-refer-to-a-jsf-component-id-in-jquery)
- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Comment: this works , thanks , do you know how can define the style of this value defined in jquery?

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea what you're asking, but it seems to be completely unrelated to the initial question. Just press `Ask Question` button on right top and flesh out over there.

Answer (score 0):

Sark,

Execute your web page and viewsource for same.

Whatever ID you will find for your `<input type='text' id='something'`

add the same id to your Jquery

var Element = "#something";

Comment: Why my id is : id="pbGfb9435b3_2d720d_2d478d_2d8183_2d657b3839216b_j_id1:j_idt5:email" ?

Comment: Because you're using portlets.

Comment: then i can't use this jquery?