# JSF or jQuery & REST

Tags: jquery, jsf, rest

Why should I use JSF?

Let's create a table. I could use a jQuery plugin jqGrid and let the data come in via REST. Or I could use JSF (RichFaces dataTable).

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: Is this a question? A suggestion?

Comment: Don't forget PrimeFaces. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the need of JSF. When UI can be achieved from css html javascript jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Why you ask if you should? Somebody forces you to do so? :)

Answer (score 2):

JSF alone is not enough, you will need some library on top of this, like Richfaces or Icefaces... It quickly amounts to a HUGE complexity, and my advice would be not to go in this direction unless you have solid experience in these technologies, or somebody in your team has.

The JS/REST solution is perfectly viable, until you need to page your table on the server (thousands of rows). In this case, the REST calls and JS will become quite complex, and Richfaces can help.

And a personal comment: the six months I've been doing JSF have been the biggest PITA of all my long programming career. I was overwhelmed by the complexity, the subtle lifecycle bugs, the lack of proper HTML request/response cycle... Maybe with a good JSF architect and a strict framework, I could've been more productive, maybe not... One thing is sure: I'll never choose JSF again for any kind of project, there are too much excellent alternatives out there.

Comment: You should have used PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Civici, isn't it a kind of spam to advertise your own technology without telling one reason?

Comment: There are thousands of reasons, I can't mention them all here. Read:http://www.primefaces.org/whyprimefaces.html

Comment: And PrimeFaces doesn't really need advertisement.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is against what solendil told you. Currently, I am a 3rd year university student. At the beginning of this year, I took a module about EJB 3.0 from January to May. After that, I got the 1st Internship of my life last summer using EJB, Java Servlet (i.e. the old technologies) to develop a web application. As you can see, I can safely call myself a beginner at developing JavaEE application.

I moved on to learn about JSF this September for my Project-based module and I must say I am very satisfied with it. JSF can really help you save the time spending on a variety of troublesome stuffs using the old Servlet such as input validation, writing scripts that can be used in all browsers, etc. Besides, at the moment, there are a number of frameworks that can add significant value to your JSF projects such as PrimeFaces, RichFaces, etc. These frameworks can enable you to do wonders that would surely take you a long time learning how to do using jQuery. As a beginner, I really appreciate the power of these frameworks.

Moreover, it's undeniable fact that you will definitely face problems while coding in JSF. However, I don't think problems with jQuery&REST are easier to solve than problems with JSF. Since you have already joined StackOverflow, I think you shouldn't be worried about facing troubles anyway ^^. Many people here such as BalusC are extremely active and pro in JavaEE. If you meet any tough troubles, just ask and "godlike" people will help you =). Up until now, I believe all my questions regarding JSF have been answered perfectly. I have never got stuck at any problems for too long. I think you will too!