# Jsf component libraries with Spring MVC

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc

Can I use  jsf component libraries(primefaces)  with spring mvc .I have problem with client side development so i want a simple way of creating user interfaces .And I dont like jsf life cycle .I need a way of using component libraries.

Comment: I am currently trying using jsp ,apache tiles and jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSF and Spring MVC have completely different ideologies. The one is a component based MVC framework and the other is a request based MVC framework. Mixing this makes no sense. You normally choose the one or the other. A component based MVC framework has the advantage that it minimizes the HTML/CSS/JS boilerplate code and the server side request processing, but this brings the disadvantage back that you don't have fine grained control over the generated HTML/CSS/JS and the server side request processing. For that you'd need a request based MVC framework. But this has in turn the disadvantage that you need to write all that HTML/CSS/JS boilerplate and server side request processing yourself.

If you want to stick to Spring MVC and want a rich UI, I suggest to look at a JavaScript based UI library, such as jQuery UI.

#### See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved from CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery/4424775#4424775)