# Submitting form from jQuery gives javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/ - View / could not be restored

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have a JSF 1.2 page which has radio buttons to choose one of 2 options. I have a jQuery function to submit the form with a change in action, but give this error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/buildVehicle.jsf - View /buildVehicle.jsf could not be restored.
root cause 
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/buildVehicle.jsf - View /buildVehicle.jsf could not be restored.
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:189)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
```

Here is the jQuery function which submits to to render the same view with some change in request param:

```
var make = $('input:radio[name=selectMake]:checked').val(); //returns NI/IN     
$("form#buildVehicleForm").attr("action", "/buildVehicle/buildVehicle.jsf?action=initTrim&make=" + make);
$('form#buildVehicleForm').submit();
```

In the JSF page I am using simple HTML radio buttons. I cannot change it to JSF `<h:selectOneRadio>` component, because the HTML code that was given to me, it is not easy to convert to JSF code.

```
<div class="filedItem margin-10px floatLeft">   
    <input type="radio" id="id1" name="selectMake" onchange="changeMake()" value="N"  />                       
</div>
<div class="filedItem margin-10px floatLeft">
<input type="radio" id="id2"  name="selectMake" onchange="changeMake()" value="I"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're completely working your path around JSF. This is not going to work. JSF requires the POST request to have a reference to the view state which is in normal JSF forms identified by a hidden field with the name `javax.faces.ViewState`. If you'd like to take full control over HTML, then you should rather use simple JSP/Servlet instead or an action based MVC framework like Spring MVC, not a JSF page with a managed bean.

As to your *real* problem for which you thought that this is the solution,

> *In the JSF page I am using simple HTML radio buttons. I cannot change it to JSF `<h:selectOneRadio>` component, because the HTML code that was given to me, it is not easy to convert to JSF code.*

In that case, [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk) [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) component may be very helpful. That component comes with an additional `layout` attribute of `spread` which allows you to position the radio buttons everywhere in the markup you want using [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html), without ending up in a `<table>` as the JSF standard `<h:selectOneRadio>` component does.

E.g.

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.foos}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
...
<div class="filedItem margin-10px floatLeft">
    <t:radio for="foo" index="0" />
</div>
<div class="filedItem margin-10px floatLeft">
    <t:radio for="foo" index="1" />
</div>
...
```

*(by the way, your CSS classes are somewhat fishy, I'd suggest to work on that as well, but that's a completelely separate subject)*

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the quick reply! I am using Sun's RI Mojarro JSF implementation. I cannot have the t:radio, is there somethign with richfaces? I am supposed to use JSF, JSTL & Richfaces only.

Comment: Well, that's bad luck. Your best bet would be writing a custom renderer for `<h:selectOneRadio>`. Tomahawk is open source, so that may give some insights. RichFaces doesn't have a similar component. Only Tomahawk, ICEfaces and PrimeFaces have. The ICEfaces one is actually a clone of Tomahawk. Alternatively you could also convince your lead to use Tomahawk. In less than a hour you'd be ready instead of days or maybe weeks.

Comment: Oh, by the way, please don't be victim of the old myth that Tomahawk only works with MyFaces, not with Mojarra. That is complete nonsense.

Comment: Hi BalusC, what is the best way for me to hit the server based on a radio button change (with the change in value)? I hate using selectoneradio, beacuse it puts a table in the generated html, if I did use it, there is no action attribute for selectoneradio. If I use HTML input radio elements and submit from JS it does not work. This seems pretty simple with other frameworks, but with JSF it seems liek my hands are tied.

Comment: Your hands are not tied by JSF. Your hands are tied by business restrictions you have. It's not JSF's fault that you may not use Tomahawk. It's a matter of dropping one or two JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` and replacing `<h:selectOneRadio>` by `<t:selectOneRadio>` with `<t:radio>`. Before ranting on JSF, I suggest to start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery Once again, discuss with your lead. The restriction to not use Tomahawk ends nowhere.