# JSF 2. How do I force close a popup window before continuing navigation?

Tags: jsf-2, popup

I have this piece of code for render a popup, using f:ajax:

```
                        <h:commandButton id ="botonAcceso"
                                    value="#{msg['login.enter']}"
                                    styleClass="botonPeque"
                                    action="#{usuarioAuditoriaLogBean.entraAplicacion}">

                        <f:ajax disabled="true"
                                render=":login:errorAcceso"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{usuarioAuditoriaLogBean.popup}" id="errorAcceso">
                        <ui:fragment>
                            <script>window.open('#{usuarioAuditoriaLogBean.url}');</script>
                        </ui:fragment>
                    </h:panelGroup>
```

I want the person, who is trying to log, must first close the popup if the logging process fails, to try to log again. How can I do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INMO you should not use widnow.open in this scenario... cause you have no control over it after its being opened , instead

1) You can use a third party JSF Components Library like Primefaces , they got [Modal Dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf)

2)You can use jQuery Modal Dialog , [here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439565/617373)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer. I have chosen your first option, and I have updated the question.

Comment: Actually its a completely different question.. you should have to accept the answer and post a new question... (I dont think you need to use the render on the dialog , it wont be displayed until .show() anyway ) , Take a look at this primefaces example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf  , And change the onclick="dlg1.show()" into oncomplete="dlg1.show()" so the dialog will be displayed after usuarioAuditoriaLogBean.entraAplicacion will be executed on the server

Comment: Ok. I'll post a new question. Thanks again!