# JQuery dialog in JSF page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to implement question dialog in JSF page. Simply explained I want the user to confirm (Yes or No) before he deletes a row into JSF table. I tried to implement this JavaScript dialog but something is wrong.

```
function questiondialog(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "No": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            } 
        }
    }); 
}  


<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{beam.deleterow}"
                    onclick="questiondialog()"  >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

When I click the button there is not dialog.

**EDIT**
After spending half a day in cutting the code slice by slice I found the problem: This is the code that is working:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Accordion
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

                // Tabs
                $('#tabs').tabs();


                // Dialog           
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 600,
                    buttons: {
                        "Ok": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        }, 
                        "Cancel": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        } 
                    }
                });

                // Dialog Link
                $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true
                });

                // Slider
                $('#slider').slider({
                    range: true,
                    values: [17, 67]
                });

                // Progressbar
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: 20 
                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Dialog NOTE: Dialog is not generated by UI in this demo so it can be visually styled in themeroller-->
        <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
        <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>

        <!-- ui-dialog -->
        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
            <p>Dialog Test</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I turns out that I need also div layer to display the dialog. How I can use this code with this AJAX JSF button?

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: try onclick="questiondialog(); return false;"

Answer (score 3):

Change `autoOpen: false` to `autoOpen: true`.

The jQuery-UI-Dialog documentation (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) clearly says,

> When autoOpen is true the dialog will open automatically when dialog
>   is called. If false it will stay hidden until .dialog("open") is
>   called on it.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

before

```
$('#dialog').dialog({....
```

INMO you better remove the `autoOpen` at all

Also know that you can't do confirm dialog like this... I mean if you want to stop the workflow with open dialog and continue it or discard it you should change your dialog `Yes` and `No` buttons behavior... but that's a diff question...

> In short : you should open dialog from a button (but don't use that
>   button action to delete row, instead execute another hidden button
>   click with jquery , and that button will be the one with action
>   attribute set to call bean method that deletes the row...) cause
>   opening a dialog from mouse click is differnt than call js built in
>   confirm function , cause the confirm function stop the workflow ,
>   while opening a dialog does not...

**take a  look at this** [complete example of jQuery dialogs + JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439565/617373)

**EDIT**

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" oneven="function(data){if(data.status==='success'){openDialogFunc();}}"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: I think that the OP definitely needs to remove the autoOpen:false.  The documentation says that when autoOpen is set to false, the dialog will not be displayed until there is a subsequent call to $.dialog('open')

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. I added all the JS code into the JSF page and CSS code but the dialog is not opening.

Comment: have you looked at the example I the link i posted? did you include all the needed js and css ? what do u see in the firebug console ?

Comment: Post updated. It turns out that there was code missing. Would you show me once again how I use JSF and AJAX button with JQuery dialog, please.

Comment: @user1285928 edited my answer if that what you were looking for, but I really think that you should look at the link i posted... its a complete working example, (just noticed that you r wrote your question... you should have start a new one with a proper subject: "how to create custom confirm dialog with jquery/JSF2"), for now I only posted a way to open a dialog - instead of how to program a confirm dialog....