# Ajax with JSF gives "The requested content cannot be loaded." error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working on my Course Final Project and I'm using JSF with AJAX, but I'm having some errors.

Currently I'm using JSF 2.0 and [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), a jQuery plugin. In a given page I have one dataTable that loads my content. Each row of this table have a link that will open a edit page for the clicked row. Note that in the fact any new page is opened, just a modal appears in screen.

[image: If you don't know, this's a modal window]

So, when user click in row the "edit page" will appears, but this will appears as modal (this's why I'm using Fancybox).

**Following is my code to do this:**

```
<h:dataTable id="minhaTabela" styleClass="table table-hover" var="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinas}" selection="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada}" selectionMode="single" >
    <h:column>
        <a class="various fancybox.ajax">
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.nome}" />
        </a>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>

(...)

$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 400,
    maxHeight   : 125,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    width       : 400,
    height      : 125,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "edit.xhtml",
        data    : { idDisciplina : '#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada.id}' }, 
        dataType: "html"                
    }
});
```

**And my edit.xhtml (don't is dynamically yet, it's for test):**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control adicionar" id="nome" />
        <br />
        <a type="button" href="#" id="excluir" class="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-left">Excluir</a>
            <a type="button" href="#" id="enviar" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Salvar</a>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

When I try to click in a row, the Fancybox open the modal, but I receive the following error:

[image: My error when use ajax :(]

### If I delete Ajax in Fancybox...

(and add href="edit.xhtml" to my link)

```
<h:column>
    <a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="edit.xhtml">
         <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.nome}" />
    </a>
</h:column>

(...)

$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 400,
    maxHeight   : 125,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    width       : 400,
    height      : 125,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

[image: This works, but how I can send the "disciplina" to edit page - summarizing, how I can edit "disciplina" by this way?]

My page loads, but by this way how I can send informations to edit.xhtml process the informations? Taking the opportunity, it's a better way to do the same thing? I don't know if I'm doing the right way, because I didn't find any tutorial or question similar to this in Google.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434558/how-to-open-modal-pop-up-in-jsf-2-using-jquery) can help you. BTW, is there an issue to use a JSF implementation like Primefaces? Take a look to their showcase [page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) if you can.

Comment: Yes, now I'm trying to use Primefaces, but I'm getting a lot of errors and I don't know why :/