# JavaScript Alert box with Frameworks

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, alert

Currently I'm programming with JSF 2.2 and i would like to know if there is any framework component that behave in the same way a javascript alert box like:

```
<script>

    function PopUpOP() {
    setInterval(function(){alert("Hey!")}, 1800000);
     }       
</script>
```

I would like to have the window open as a modal window and get the user attention no matter on which browser tab the user is working on like alert box do.

Thank you!

Comment: what's wrong with pure javascript :) ?

Comment: anyway if you want modals, bootstrap's modals is better than just alerts, in that case I suggest Bootsfaces

Comment: @niceman - nothing, but i want decorate it like a component in primefaces or something like this. Modals dont get users attention like alert box.

Comment: hmmm I don't agree that modals don't get users attention like alert box, modals is better in my opinion(and you can make blocking modals if you want). anyway why a component for just `alert` ? a component in my assumption should abstract away many things, not just `alert` !

Comment: @niceman - When an alert box is called, the page is also called too. When a modal is opened, the user will only see if you are on the system page. Understood?

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434558/how-to-open-modal-pop-up-in-jsf-2-using-jquery