# How JSF and JSP differs client-side?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the need of JSF. When UI can be achieved from css html javascript jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery)

I'm learning JSF for the first time, and am just not seeing the inherent difference from JSP, besides (perhaps) a cleaner separation of presentation and business logic.

My *understanding* of JSF:

- Client requests a JSF page
- The `FacesServlet` (which comes with JSF) routes the request to a custom (written by the developer) JSF controller
- JSF controller knows which models/views/beans to use to handle the request
- JSF pages (`.jsf`), which contain a mixture of HTML, CSS, JS and special JSF tags are interrogated by the JSF controller, and used to generate HTML/CSS/JS code to be sent back to the client browser

My *understanding* of JSP:

- Client requests a JSP page
- web.xml routes the request to the correct controller/handler
- Controller/handler determines which JSP file (`.jsp`) to use in the response
- This JSP file contains a mixture of HTML, CSS, JS and special JSP tags that get interrogated and ultimately generate HTML/CSS/JS to be sent back to client browser

In both cases, you end up with intermingled client-side (HTML, CSS, JS) and Java code in the form of tag libraries.

- **How is JSF an improvement over JSP**?
- **How is the JSF life cycle any different (really!) than JSP**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-jsf-and-jsp/

Comment: **How JSF and JSP differs client-side?"* If all goes to plan, JSF/JSP should be 'identical & indistinguishable' on the client side.