# JSF 2 compatible with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsf-2

so I have been tasked with finding out whether an existing JSF project can incorporate jQuery Mobile. I have only finished college 2 months ago so I have limited experience, which is why I am turning to you guys for help.

The project is using eclipse with JSF,Maven and Spring. At the moment it is my belief that only jQuery mobile 1.0 is fully usable with JSF. One of the pre-requisites of the project however states that the latest version of jQuery Mobile must be used.

So my question is this, is jQuery 1.2 fully usable with JSF? Or does it have parts that are not compatible.

If so does anyone have any good tutorials they can link to on how to use this?

Thanks in advance for any help provided, any information that needs clearing up or any clarification needed just let me know.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used jQuery Mobile 1.0 in combination with JSF2 in the past, and things worked pretty well. Not sure about the 1.2 version, but I don't know any reason why that wouldn't work.

As mentioned in Chaney's comment, binding and retrieving data to the jQuery controls can sometimes be troublesome. You might want to check out [PrimeFaces Mobile](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf), which takes most of that burden off you and should get you started pretty quickly (if it doesn't conflict with any other component libraries you are using). The latest version of PrimeFaces Mobile seems to use jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.