# When should I use JSF instead of Javascript+HTML+CSS UI?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsf, jakarta-ee

I' m developing a client-server application - it is a simple decision support system for credit risk evaluation.It has a server which is based on Hibernate+PostgreSQL+some Java EE technologies and a client which must display some web forms for a user (input fileds for age,job,credit history, comboboxes,tables, etc.).And the problem I don't know what should I choose for client:JSF or Javascript UI with HTML and CSS? As far as I know Jsf is server-side technology but i don't understand this completely.What does it mean server-side GUI?

Detail explanation will be helpful.

Comment: btw Check out local Stack Overflow [JSF info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). There you can also find a lot of links to useful resources.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the need of JSF. When UI can be achieved from css html javascript jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Note that JSF doesn't run in the client. JSF just generates HTML/CSS/JS which in turn runs in client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF components provide the HTML, CSS and JS for the UI encapsulated in reusable modules.

That said, they have a step learning curve. If you do not know how they work, don't try to test them in a real Project. When you get to have some time, study them by yourself and once you get the grasp of them decide if you use them.

Comment: Your last remark is IMHO a bit overly general. Do you mean only JSF has a "step" learning curve, or everything has and that you should never use anything in a real project that you don't know?