# JSF 2 not firing setter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My bean isn't firing my setter method and I can't figure out why.

Here's the import part of the xhtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateTextInput(val, box) {
        //document.getElementById(box).value=val; 
    }
</script>
```

```html
Min value: </td><td><input type="range" name="minVal"    min="-100" max="200" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value, 'minValInput');"/><h:inputText id="minValInput" value="#{myClass.minVal}"></h:inputText>
<h:form><h:commandButton value="#{myClass.status}" action="welcome">
```

And here's my bean:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String status = "";
private int minVal = 0;

public String getStatus() {
  if(status == "") {
    status = "Start";
  }

  return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
}

public int getMinVal() {
  System.out.println("*********************" + minVal);
  return minVal;
}

public void setMinVal(int minVal) {
  System.out.println("*********************" + minVal);
  this.minVal = minVal;
}
```

My command button getter and setter's fire fine, but from my output I can tell minVal's getters are executed twice while the setter is never executed.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here but can't quite figure it out.  Does anyone see something I overlooked?

Comment: Could be just a side note.  Your `xhtml` (as shown here) is **not well formed**. Look at the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `<h:inputText>` isn't inside a `<h:form>`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) allows you to use [`<h:inputText type="range">`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit) instead and JSF component library [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) offers a [`<p:slider>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml) to have a range input in jQuery UI look'n'feel. You may find it easier than fiddling around with plain HTML and JS.

#### See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved from CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Thanks you so much!  I'm going to give OmniFaces a shot.  The problem I'm now having is I've only used Mojerra from the dynamic web project ui wizard in eclipse.  I've downloaded and dropped the jar into my project, where do I define OmniFaces?

Comment: That's basically it. Just read the showcase examples for installation, configuration and usage detail. The blueish `<h:inputText type="range">` part in my answer is a link. Click it (and scroll back to top ;) ).