# Disable a button on click and call its action

Tags: java, jsp

I need to disable a button on clicking it but need its action to be triggered from my jsp page. But when disabling the button, the backend call doesnt happen. Please assist. Can i have it set from the client side itself rather than using a bean variable and rendering the disabled attribute based on the bean variable value.

`<h:commandButton id="ct1"  styleClass="right"
     value="Follow"   action="#{testBB.confirm}" onclick="this.disabled= true;" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<p:commandButton> not working when disable="true" initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647315/pcommandbutton-not-working-when-disable-true-initially) or possibly [Action of <h:commandButton> not getting invoked when “disabled=true” is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072437/action-of-hcommandbutton-not-getting-invoked-when-disabled-true-is-set)

Comment: why not use js and set <button disabled="disabled" .... >text</button> onclick?

Comment: sorry i dint get u

Comment: i tried using js but still the same issue

Comment: Can i have it set from the client side itself rather than using a bean variable and rendering the disabled attribute based on the bean variable value.