# Jsf+Primefaces responsive design

Tags: jsf, primefaces, responsive-design

I have started working of **JSF+Primefaces** latest version for my website is this somehow possible i can make my design responsive with these technology. I do not want to use **Primefaces** mobile or i do not want to create two different page for same functionality

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ try to check new primefaces showcase with desktop PC, tablet and mobile phone (for example using Ripple in Chrome ). It is "responsive" and looks nice on all devices. Tbh did not tested it

Answer (score 14):

[PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/downloads/) 6.x has responsive design updates, including a [Responsive Grid](https://www.primefaces.org/responsive-grid/).

The grid is not a JSF component, it's a simple div with a `ui-grid` classes.

Example of 3 column layout:

```
<div class="ui-grid">
   <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col1</div>
   <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
   <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
 </div>
```

---

In real case scenarios having only a grid won't fill the requirements so you should usually use some frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Both frameworks provide CSS/Javascript rules, they can be applied easily on the JSF components, for example if you have a button:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn" value="Button">
</h:commandButton>
```

[btn](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) is a bootstrap CSS class.

You might run into some components which won't accept such styles, like the table of Primefaces, in these cases you should write your own [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)/Javascript in order to maintain the responsiveness.

**See more**

- [JSF and Twitter Bootstrap Integration](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/jsf-and-twitter-bootstrap-integration/)

Comment: You may not use `div` directly as this is a plain HTML tag which is not a JSF component. Instead, consider using JSF `<h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-grid" layout="block">` or PrimeFaces `p:panel`. Then in both cases it will be controllable by the respective JSF engine. All the nice things like `rendered="#{someELcode.bla()}"` is then possible.

Comment: No, as what I have learned, you should avoid direct HTML tags as they are not controlled by JSF engine. Especially when it comes to `<form>` instead of `<h:form>` tag which will not invoke your action method in your backing bean. Also using `<input>` instead of `<h:commandButton|Link>` will not trigger it. Using `<head>` instead of `<h:head>` will not load any JavaScripts from your JSF engine (including all other faces).

Comment: That is what I have learned on training. :-) And I have tried it out and had exactly that, no action method was called. Well, for `<div>`, as I know, it will end up as body for some JSF tag.

Comment: This doesn't mean you can't use html, after all, all the final output by these components is HTML, your point is right for specific components that you need to harvest an input from them or so, but to have a layout it's a good practice to use html rather than having extra components on the stack, so using div and span etc.. is a good practice

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jqu

Comment: Yes, of course. You *can* use HTML in JSF, I also use `<li>` and `<ul` but I instinctively try to find a JSF tag as a good replacement. Don't think that JSF is yet-another template engine like Groovy or Smarty (PHP) is. It is a component engine under JavaEE like Swing is under JavaSE and it controls JSF component aka. tags.

Comment: I prefer `<h:panelGroup class="some-class" layout="block">` over `<div class="some-class">` for the said reasons, as it (JSF) can be controlled by engine (e.g. `rendered` attribute which is **not** CSS `display:none`!) and allows EL code.

Comment: Use as suitable, this is my argument, if you don't need a rendered why to to use panelGroup in the first place ? Using div is much faster as none of the rendering part is going to take place, such as the panelGroup case