# JSF when render databale lose the datatable JS

Tags: jsf

i have problem when i load the model and press edit on the edit button then render the datatable i lose the JS sorting i'm using datatables and i don't want to render the datatable JS again with edit please can help me.

```
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Branches</h3>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:commandButton value="Add New Branch" id="createBranchBtn" pt:data-loading-text="Loading..." pt:autocomplete="off" class="btn btn-primary sye-action-btn-loading">
                        <f:param name="pageType" value="create"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="box-body table-responsive no-padding branches-datatable">
                    <div class="SYE-modal">  </div>
                    <h:panelGroup id="branchesListDiv" layout="block" class="container-fluid">
                        <h:dataTable id="example1" binding="#{index}" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"  value="#{branchesMB.list}" var="branch">
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header" >
                                    <h:outputText value="#"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{index.rowIndex+1}"/>
                                <f:facet name="footer" >
                                    <b><h:outputText value="#"/></b>
                                </f:facet>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Branch Name"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchName}"/>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <b><h:outputText value="Branch Name"/></b>
                                </f:facet>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Address"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchAddress}"/>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <b><h:outputText value="Address"/></b>
                                </f:facet>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Abbreviation"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchAbbreviation}"/>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <b><h:outputText value="Abbreviation"/></b>
                                </f:facet>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column headerClass="syeActionDatatable">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText  value="Action"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <b><h:outputText  value="Action"/></b>
                                </f:facet>
                                <div class="btn-group" >
                                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class='dropdown-menu pull-right'>
                                        <li>
                                            <!--pt:data-toggle="modal" pt:data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"-->
                                            <h:commandLink  actionListener="#{branchesMB.setEntityEditObject(branch)}" class="editDatatable" >
                                                <f:ajax onevent="load" onerror="load" render=":branchesForm:branchEditArea"/>
                                                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>
                                                Edit
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <!--onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) return false"-->
                                            <h:commandLink  action="#{branchesMB.destroy()}" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'))
                                                        return false;">
                                                <f:ajax render=":branchesForm:branchEditArea"/>
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{branchesMB.entityDeleteObject}" value="#{branch}"/>
                                                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>
                                                Delete
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Branch</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <h:panelGroup id="branchEditArea" layout="block" class="box-body">
                                            <ui:include src="/view/includes/messages.xhtml"/>
                                            <h:inputHidden value="#{branchesMB.entityEditObject}" converter="BranchesConverter"/>
                                            <h:panelGroup id="branchNameDiv" layout="block" class="form-group">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Branch Name" for="branchName"/>
                                                <h:inputText id="branchName" class="form-control" value="#{branchesMB.entityEditObject.branchName}" />
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:panelGroup id="branchAddressDiv" layout="block" class="form-group">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Branch Address" for="branchAddress"/>
                                                <h:inputText id="branchAddress" class="form-control" value="#{branchesMB.entityEditObject.branchAddress}"/>
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                            <h:panelGroup id="branchAbbreviationDiv" layout="block" class="form-group">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Abbreviation" for="branchAbbreviation"/>
                                                <h:inputText id="branchAbbreviation" class="form-control" value="#{branchesMB.entityEditObject.branchAbbreviation}"/>
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <!--pt:data-dismiss="modal"-->
                                        <h:commandButton id="close" value="Close" class="btn btn-default" >
                                            <f:ajax render="branchesForm:branchesListDiv"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>

                                        <h:commandButton id="edit" value="Edit" action="#{branchesMB.update()}" class="btn btn-primary sye-action-btn-loading" pt:data-loading-text="Loading..." pt:autocomplete="off">
                                            <f:ajax render=":branchesForm:branchesListDiv,:branchesForm:branchEditArea, @this" execute="branchEditArea branchesForm:branchesListDiv"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                        <!--                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="box-footer">
                    Branches
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
  <ui:define name="scriptPlugins">
            <h:panelGroup id="scriptPlugins">
                <script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/SYE-2.1.1/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/SYE-2.1.1/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:define>
```

Comment: *"and i don't want to render the datatable JS again"*, well then it stops here. There are no solutions as long as you want to fulfill this requirement. Consider syncing sorting with server side (like PrimeFaces does) instead of performing it entirely client side.

Comment: look i use datatables from datatables.net its framework and when i render the datatable i should load the javascript again

Comment: That's correct. It's a client side library, not a server side one. On the other hand, it's quite possible that you missed the point of JSF. Without JSF, you'd just have used JS/jQuery to add the new item to the table without refreshing it. Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery and http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml

Comment: I don't want to use primefaces

Comment: Then you thus need to write/manage JS code yourself instead of letting JSF/PrimeFaces do it for you :)