# How to implement PrimeFaces-like UI with JSP and Spring MVC?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsf

I start study Spring MVC and I don't understand some things. Concretely - use JSP. I've worked with Primefaces. And in PrimeFaces I have UI elements - `commandButton`, `panelGrid`, `column`, `outputText`, etc. But in JSP I don't have those elements. I have only HTML and JSTL. Are there any tools for building interface in JSP like Primefaces? For example in PrimeFaces:

```
<h:outputText value="ID: "/>
<p:inputText value="#{QCforCCReportBean.operatorID}"/>

<h:outputText value="Nickname: "/>
<p:inputText value="#{QCforCCReportBean.operatorNickname}"/>
```

How do it in JSP?

Comment: Just write HTML/CSS/JS yourself. PrimeFaces is a jQuery based JSF component library. So just throw in jQuery and jQuery UI yourself. It appears that you never really learned basic HTML/CSS/JS before JSF. This is actually not a good sign and will make the learning curve of JSF much steeper. I can only applaud stepping back to "plain HTML" with a request based framework so that you learn the basics and ultimately face which boilerplate JSF has hidden away for you. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421839

Comment: Yes, primefaces - it first tools that I encountered. I do not understent how tools use now in java web developing. Now I use JavaEE+JSF (it is one project in my job) but i study Spring MVC and I want know how to build beautiful UI in spring