# Bootsfaces vs Bootstrap

Tags: jsf, bootstrap-4, bootsfaces

I have used Bootstrap while development of Web Application. Now I have started learning of BootsFaces. While learning very first question pop up in my mind is

> **What is Exactly difference between Bootstrap and BootsFaces? and
>   what are their pros and cons over each other?**

I searched for these answers but there wasn't any answer which make my doubt clear. Please help me for these questions.

Answer (score 6):

BootsFaces is a [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) component library which generates HTML that uses Bootstrap. BootsFaces allows you to easily work with Bootstrap in a JSF application. Comparing them would be more or less the same as comparing red paint to a red painted board.

Some info from the [BootsFaces showcase](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/basic.jsf) on this subject, specifically on layouting:

> ### Why BootsFaces? Why not using Bootstrap natively?
>
> BootsFaces takes full advantage of Bootstrap's Grid system while maintaining the benefits of being a JSF framework. Actually, we believe it's more concise and more expressive than programming Bootstrap natively. Convince yourself: inspect the source code of the demo in your browser's source code view. After reformatting, the form is 81 lines. The JSF source is is 45 lines.
>
> BootsFaces being a JSF framework means that you can leverage Bootstrap's layout feature using - for example - the JSF templating system and JSF's conditional rendering to achieve and maintain very complex layouts without much effort.
>
> This website is an example itself: it uses a page template with `ui:insert` and `ui:include` and the pages are `ui:compositions`.

See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved with JavaScript libraries such as jQuery and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-with-javascript-libraries-such)

Comment: The question is tagged "bootstrap-4", so I'd like to add that the BootsFaces 1.x is built on the older version Bootstrap 3. The yet-to-be-release version BootsFaces 2.x is built on Bootstrap 4.