# How to integrate React project in JSF framework?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, jsf

I was trying to integrate a **React project** into a **JSF framework** as a module
I'm still looking for the **correct path** to take ?
what should I do and use to have the **best performance and behaviors** ?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to use webpack to create a dist (bundle js) and then call that bundle as a script in xhtml page
it works, but I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-with-javascript-libraries-such