How to show React popup in jsf application?
I have a requirement where I need to show a react popup dialog when clicked a button which existed in JSF application. So, when user clicked that button in JSF, it should somehow show React popup which has some react js components
I tried to create web component of React app(vite), but when integrated with JSF, Jquery of JSF and Build file of React js got some conflicts, Even I tried to build using npm run build , but no luck, same conflicts occurs.
EDIT: I have attached code snippet for web component
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Sample } from "./components/Sample";


class SampleWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ["buttontext", "popupmessage"];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.render();
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(oldValue: string | null, newValue: string | null) {
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      this.render();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const buttonText = this.getAttribute("buttontext") || "Click Me";
    const popupMessage =
      this.getAttribute("popupmessage") || "This is your popup message!";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Sample buttonText={buttonText} popupMessage={popupMessage} />,
      this.shadowRoot
    );
  }
}

and my vite.config.ts has following contents
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env": {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/index.tsx",
      name: "sample",
      fileName: (format) => `sample.${format}.js`,
      formats: ["umd"],
    },
    target: "esnext",
  },
});


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community I have added some more details (code) for better understanding

How does JSF exist in this setup?

@f1sh there is one JSF application , where on click of button in JSF, I need to show react js popup displaying grid wihin that .

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-with-javascript-libraries-such
